# Bash script with dynamic number of user inputed variables

Tags: bash

I made the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
read var1
ffmpeg  -ss $var1 -y -i "$1" -frames:v 1 -q:v 2 "1$.jpg" 
exit
```

Which works fine for a single file. The scripts waits for input and then passes it to ffmpeg. But how do I repurpose it for multiple files, i.e. so the script asks for input for every passed argument without doing it manually like this?

```
#!/bin/bash
read var1
read var2
read var3
ffmpeg  -ss $var1 -y -i "$1" -frames:v 1 -q:v 2 "$1.jpg" 
ffmpeg  -ss $var2 -y -i "$2" -frames:v 1 -q:v 2 "$2.jpg" 
ffmpeg  -ss $var3 -y -i "$3" -frames:v 1 -q:v 2 "$3.jpg"
```

Comment: arrays, but I would be more tempted to accept the inputs as command-line arguments. If you don't need to get all the input at the beginning, you can also use a fairly simple loop with `shift`

Comment: Please don't ask for input. It is just bad practice 9 times out of 10. It means your script cannot be automated, it cannot be repeated, your user can easily enter the wrong value and then will have to start from the beginning etc. Just read everything as parameters.

Comment: @terdon My bash scripting skills are extremely limited so this seemed like the most simplest solution.

Comment: @user5672 I'm sorry, I didn't mean that to come across as any kind of attack. We all need to start from somewhere and being new to scripting isn't a bad thing! If you want, you can post a new question, explaining what you want the script to do, what your `read` will be expecting, and we can show you how to simplify it by using arguments instead.

Comment: @terdon No worries, your comment wasn't interpreted as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `for` loop:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for param in "$@"; do
    read -p "Enter ... something: " -r var
    ffmpeg  -ss "$var" -y -i "$param" -frames:v 1 -q:v 2 "${param}.jpg" 
done
```

`for param in "$@"; do` can be written like `for param do`

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted. I just modified the script so it strips the input filename extension on output.